# componentDidMount only fires once when rendering multiple Component via map()

Tags: reactjs

I am facing a weird problem. I've written a React component which renders multiple custom child components via the array.map()-method like this:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IParentProps> {
   return (
       this.children.map((item, idx) => {
           return (<Child customProperty={item}>);
       }
   );
}
```

All of my children get rendered, but componentDidMount gets called just once and not, like I would like it to be, every time a Child components gets created. It's crazy. I am using React 15.6.2 (can't upgrade, it's a, SharePoint 2019 solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further Murats answer, what you're likely looking for is [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the lifecycle hook. `componentDidMount` means as the name suggests that the component is mounted (does not mean the render() function is done). It also does not get called for rendering elements at all.